# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject not decoding special character

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am currently serializing an object like this below.

"record" is a string array which has special character in it, like >,<,& etc

The first index in record is "<" and this is a xml special character and which is converted to "&lt"; by SecurityElement.Escape(record[x]);.

After that when I try to escape it using HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode, which is converted into \u0026lt .

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] record = { "<", ">", "John & James" };
            for (int x = 0; x < record.Length; x++)
            {
                string xmlEscaped = SecurityElement.Escape(record[x]); 
                result.Add($"F{235}_{"Property"}{x + 1}", HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(xmlEscaped));
            }
string json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

and the result from json is

{"F235_Property1":"\u0026lt;","F235_Property2":"\u0026gt;","F235_Property3":"John \u0026amp; James"}

When I deserialize the same json, I use

```
var jsonConverted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

But after deserialization, the special characters converted are not converting back to original.
Example - \u0026lt is not converting back to "&lt";

Please help me on this to get resolved .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code above is incomplete and does not compile.  Can you please provide a [mcve] that we can run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have made necessary edit to the code. Please have a look in to it.

Comment: @user1844283 post the actual json string. Not approximations. In almost *all* similar cases though there are no special characters. `&lt` is 3 plain-old US ASCII characters. `&` has no special meaning for JSON either. If you actually see `\u0026` in your string, its 6 plain-old US ASCII characters, not some escape sequence

Comment: All this quoting and escaping *creates* the problem. You don't need any kind of escaping to use JSON.NET. Perhaps you should post what you initially tried to do before adding all that quoting?

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[]{ "<", ">", "John & James" })` returns the string `["<",">","John & James"]`. It doesn't need any extra processing. JSON doesn't care about *XML's* special characters so it doesn't need any kind of escaping. Are you trying to mix XML and JSON perhaps?

Comment: Yes. I am mixing XML and Json. The data is stored in json format, however once deserialised the data is returned in an XML SOAP service. These are factors I can't change and need to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize your json to dictionary, and reverse every action you do before serialization for every value in key-value pairs after.